# Using views.py variables in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, django-views

I changed my mind about how a user page is populated. Previously users would select a value from a drop-down and an AJAX call would go fetch some data. The working code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<h3>Experimenter: {{ request.user }}</h3>
<h3>Response Surface: {{ surfaceModel }}</h3>
<form action="">
  <h4>
        <select id = "selectRS" name="selectRS">
                        <option value="intro">Intro</option>
                        <option value="intro2">Intro 2</option>
                        <option value="welding">Welding</option>
                        </select>
        </h4>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
...
var levels = {{ dlevels }}; // dlevels is an integer
var mtx_data = {{ mtx_init }}; //mtx_init is a 2-d array    
var rspSrf = document.getElementById("selectRS").value;
...
$.ajax({ ...
```

This works fine. But I now want to pass the value via the url, so I changed the JavaScript to this:

```
var rspSrf = {{ surfaceModel }};
```

And now the ajax won't work.

This is how the value of `surfaceModel` is being passed now:

```
url(r'^profile/intro$', 'prof_pages.views.profile', {'surfaceModel': 'intro'}, name='profile/intro'),
```

`surfaceModel` is a string, just like the drop down selection, so I'm not sure why it won't work.

I edited my code to show more of the working code.  I simply extended what was already working to try to pass a string along with the integers and arrays that are being passed to the js script.

Comment: `var rspSrf = {{ surfaceModel }};` is very much wrong. Please go through Angular tutorials.

Comment: You cannot use angularjs expression in javascript because they aren't javascript expressions.

Comment: If you write something like this `var rspSrf = {{ surfaceModel }}` in JS, I recommend you to revisit JS tutorials or maybe drink a cup of coffee before continuing...

Comment: ok so why does this work:  'var mtxrows = {{ mrows }};'?  in this case mrows is an integer value pass through the view's context dictionary.  js seems to be totally happy when the variables are numbers.  I'm going through the angular tutorials now, but I don't see the connection yet.

Comment: Please remove the angularJS tag from this question since this is a django problem

Answer (score 0):

the corrected code is:

```
var rspSrf = "{{ surfaceModel }}";
```

Even though the variable being passed is a string it still needs the double quotes.  the following reference showed the way:

http://www.mutaku.com/wp/index.php/2012/03/accessing-django-template-variables-in-javascript/

also update the title, hopefully it's clearer now
regards.